# Facebook Privacy Policy (for app that doesn't want to use user login)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-javascript-sdk, privacy-policy

I know this is a relatively open-ended question, but since facebook doesn't have any specific developer support forums themselves, I'm wondering if anyone has any advice here --

I'm building an app that uses a pre-authenticated proxy server to pull public page/page-event data from a predefined set of pages. Since there will be no need for a user login (or there will be just a single personal account's auth token tied to the proxy), I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to go about writing a privacy policy (requirement now for apps).

I know I need `Page Public Content Access` but the legal-speak required for a privacy policy about how to handle users' data and so on is tripping me up, since I won't be collecting any. It's actually an important part of the app that no login is required.

My question specifically being: a request for resources that can aid me in writing a privacy policy that will be approved, for a scenario that users' data is not actually ever supposed to be a part of the app.

Help, please, thank you!

Comment: What do you need Page Public Content Access for if you not collecting any data?

Comment: @WizKid graph api explorer `[PAGE_ID]/?fields=events{cover}` returns ```{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "E+cqQbwoHLn"
  }
}```

Comment: So you are collecting data

Comment: I am trying to access (meaning directly display, not store) data from public pages, not users. If you consider that collecting data, then yes.

Comment: Yes that is collecting data. So you need a Privacy Policy on how you handle the data

Comment: no offense, but yeah, obviously. that's the question I asked. not *whether* but *if anyone has helpful advice for resources*, which this is not.